# How to sign in using gmail in cordova android application

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, gmail

I have cordova android project.In home page i have two buttons say "member login" and "signup". I want to signup user using their google account and  login in using that gmail when the clicks "member login" button.(sign up is only to know how many members installed application)

is there any way to achieve with this using java script in button click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you to get started.
[Oauth using ngcordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/#Oauth)